# SUMPRODUCT formula errors

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want a cell to automatically display a text (T1, T2, T3, T4) based on whether or not the input in another cell is found in a table.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(C3=standards!I3:I16))>0,"T1")
```

will list for just one category, but I can't get the formula to accept multiple arrays AND specific inputs when the value is in that category.

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(C3=standards!I3:I16))>0,"T1")*(--(C3=standards!J3:j16))>0,"T2")
```

etc. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your second formula will work successfully when you will test C3 in four different data ranges. **Confirm it then I'll show you what modification is required.**

Answer (score 1):

Use AGGREGATE, it will search the range and return a number based on the column in which the value was found to the CHOOSE() function:

```
=CHOOSE(AGGREGATE(15,6,(COLUMN($I$2:$L$16)-COLUMN($I$2)+1)/($I$2:$L$16=C3),1),"T1","T2","T3","T4")
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(B253=A254:A257))>0,"T1",IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(B253=B254:B257))>0,"T2",IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(B253=C254:C257))>0,"T3",IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(B253=D254:D257))>0,"T4"))))
```

Notes:

1. Adjust the data range and criteria cell reference as necessary.
2. For any value of the criteria cell from 0 to 15, the formula returns T1 
   to T4 depending on the column the value is in.
3. If the value in the criteria cell is greater than 15, the `AGGREGATE()`
   formula will return a `#Num!` error but this formula will give `FALSE`.

Comment: What wrong you found with solution to down-vote it,,, just write your concern, otherwise I'll purse to moderator !!

Comment: Don't see what's wrong with your answer - upvoted

Comment: Thanks @Ultrasonic54321,, this encouraged me to do better & better :-)

Answer (score 0):

This `SUMPRODUCT()` formula gives the column number (of your data table) that the value from C3 is in:

`=SUMPRODUCT(1*(C3=standards!I3:L16)*COLUMN(A:D))`

and you can use that in a `CHOOSE()` formula, as in Scott's answer, or an `INDEX()` if your texts are long or might need to change.

`=CHOOSE(SUMPRODUCT(1*(C3=standards!I3:L16)*COLUMN(A:D)),"T1","T2","T3","T4")`

`=INDEX(Text_Table,SUMPRODUCT(1*(C3=standards!I3:L16)*COLUMN(A:D)))`

Note that the `SUMPRODUCT()` formula will give the wrong answer if there are multiple occurrences of the C3 value in your data table.  There are ways around this, so please comment if there might be multiple values.

The other answers will identify the first occurrence, but they'll give the correct text for the column that it's in.